# Photoshop Script: Coordinates of smart objects

Tags: javascript, coordinates, photoshop

I'm kinda new in PS scripting, and also I'm not a programmer, so I have a very basic question to ask.

How can I retrieve a smart object layer's position coordinates? When I try to get their position, my script gives me their "rasterized" position, without respecting the smart object canvas. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First select the layer in question, then run this little script:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    tell current document
        get bounds of current layer as integer
    end tell
end tell
```